# Approximately inverting functions with Monte Carlo methods

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the following problem: Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ with $n>m$ be a smooth function. I want to find input vectors $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ which yield a given output $y\in \mathbb{R}^m$, so $f(x)=y$. My idea was to start at a random vector $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and try to iteratively decrease the $L^2$-norm of the differences, so that for any $n$ we have $||f(x_{n+1})-y)||_2<||f(x_n)-y)||_2$. Would this be possible with some kind of Monte Carlo approach? Or are there any existing approaches that could be used for tackling this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to solve the optimization problem
$$
\text{minimize} \quad \frac12 \| f(x) - y \|_2^2.
$$
The optimization variable is $x \in \mathbb R^n$.
This optimization problem could be solved with a method such as gradient descent or Newton's method or Levenberg-Marquardt. Gradient descent is a simple way to go.

The derivative of the objective function
$F(x) = \frac12 \| f(x) - y \|_2^2$ is
$$
F'(x) = (f(x) - y)^T f'(x).
$$
The $m \times n$ matrix $f'(x)$ is also called the Jacobian of $f$ at $x$.
If we use the convention that the gradient of $F$ is a column vector then
\begin{align}
\nabla F(x) &= F'(x)^T \\
&= f'(x)^T (f(x) - y).
\end{align}
The gradient descent iteration is
$$
x^{k+1} = x^k - t \nabla F(x^k).
$$
If the step size $t > 0$ is sufficiently small then
the iterates $x^k$ will converge to a local minimizer of $F$.
There is a danger that we could get trapped in a local minimum,
but if the initial guess $x^0$ is good enough
then we have a good shot at converging to a value of $x$
that satisfies $f(x) = y$.